# Stacktrace involving a NSOperation release

Tags: ios, crash, stack-trace, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I receive crash reports which are quite obscure. What is the strategy with stack traces such as the following.

```
Thread 7 crashed

0 libobjc.A.dylib objc_msgSend + 9
1 Foundation -[NSOperation release] + 148
2 Foundation __release_object_op + 22
3 libdispatch.dylib _dispatch_async_f_redirect_invoke + 82
4 libdispatch.dylib _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 262
5 libsystem_c.dylib _pthread_wqthread + 294
```

I have been looking at the different threads to see if one of them could point at some specific part of my app but all the threads are waiting in some system libraries or in the main loop.

Any hint?

Bruno

Comment: Can you share more context? That stack does not seem overly obscure by itself; any confusion would come from knowing how this fits in to how you are using the NSOps. Have you tried setting breakpoints and seeing how close to the crash you can step? What is going on just prior, and what is the line that it crashes on attempting to do? Or, since this looks like it is probably part of ARC's cleanup after a scope closes, can you show how the NSOpQueue is setup?

Comment: The problem is that this is a stacktrace I'm getting automatically from users so I don't have more context and I never encountered it during testing or development.

Comment: Are you using NSOperationQueue anywhere?

Comment: Yes, I'm queuing NSOperation in the main NSOperationQueue. It seems here that the problem would be when the operation is released. But it's definitely not happening regularly since we never had the issue during testing and development.

Comment: Yes, that what it seems like. I doubt anyone will be able to help you with this unless you post some of that code. Include the relevant @interface portion as well as your initialization.